# How can I quickly map all IP addresses on my network to hostnames?

Tags: windows, networking

Any DOS commands that allow me to do so and output the data? Or any free software to do the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free software:

SolarWinds has a free IP Address Tracker.

Download it at
http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/ip_address_tracker/

It will probe for IP addresses and will associate them with names.